# Click on an image to zoom in

Tags: javascript, html, animation

I'm still a newbie when it comes to javascript, so I don't know yet how to optimize this code.

**customize.js**

```
 // Get the modal
  var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
  var modal2 = document.getElementById('myModal2');
  var modal3 = document.getElementById('myModal3');

  // Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a      caption
  var img = document.getElementById('myImg');
  var modalImg = document.getElementById("img1");
  var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");

  var img2 = document.getElementById('myImg2');
  var modalImg2 = document.getElementById("img2");
  var captionText2 = document.getElementById("caption2");

  var img3 = document.getElementById('myImg3');
  var modalImg3 = document.getElementById("img3");
  var captionText3 = document.getElementById("caption3");


  img.onclick = function(){
 modal.style.display = "block";
 modalImg.src = this.src;
 captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
  }

  img2.onclick = function(){
 modal2.style.display = "block";
 modalImg2.src = this.src;
 captionText2.innerHTML = this.alt;
  }

  img3.onclick = function(){
 modal3.style.display = "block";
 modalImg3.src = this.src;
 captionText3.innerHTML = this.alt;
  }
  // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
  var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
  var span2 = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[1];
  var span3 = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[2];
  // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
  span.onclick = function() { 
 modal.style.display = "none";
  }

  span2.onclick = function(){
 modal2.style.display = "none";
  }

  span3.onclick = function(){
 modal3.style.display = "none";
  }
```

And this how my html looks like

**HTML**

```
<li class="one-third animate-box" data-animate-effect="fadeIn">
    <img id="myImg" src="images/Images/gallery-1.jpg" alt="Ash Image Gallery 1" height="100%" width="100%">
</li>
<li class="one-third animate-box" data-animate-effect="fadeIn">
    <img id="myImg2" src="images/Images/gallery-2.jpg" alt="Ash Image Gallery 2" height="100%" width="100%">
</li>
<li class="one-third animate-box" data-animate-effect="fadeIn" >
    <img id="myImg3" src="images/Images/gallery-3.jpg" alt="Ash Image Gallery 3" height="100%" width="100%">
</li>
```

Comment: anyone help me please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### HTML

I noticed that you didn't put the `ul` or `ol` tag in your code, you need to put your `li` tags inside the a `ul` or `ol` in order to have a more semantic structure.

```
<ul id="my-images">
    <li>
        <img src="https://api.fnkr.net/testimg/350x200/00CED1/FFF/?text=img+placeholder" alt="Ash Image Gallery 1" >
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="https://api.fnkr.net/testimg/350x200/00CED1/FFF/?text=img+placeholder" alt="Ash Image Gallery 2">
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="https://api.fnkr.net/testimg/350x200/00CED1/FFF/?text=img+placeholder" alt="Ash Image Gallery 3">
    </li>
</ul>

<!-- The image zoomed in will be put inside the tag below, you should keep it in your HTML file in order to show your images -->
<div class="modal"></div>
```

### CSS

I did some very basic styling for the modal to look more attractive in the demo.

```
.modal {
    display: none;
    background: #000;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: .8;
}

.modal .modal-content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -120px;
    margin-left: -150px;
    color: #fff;
}

.modal img, .modal span {
    z-index: 10;
}
```

### JavaScript

I put all the images inside the `images` variable and also put the *modal* element in it's own variable.

Then I looped through each image using the `forEach()`, defining that for each image, which the user has clicked, it will put a `display: block` to the *modal* element and insert a piece of HTML containing an `<img>` tag and a `<span>` tag with the `alt` property in it.

And last but not less important, everytime that the user clicks in the *modal* area with the `display: block` activated, it will put a `display: none` automatically on it.

```
var images = document.querySelectorAll('#my-images img'),
    modal = document.querySelector('.modal');

// Loops through the all the images selected...
images.forEach(function (image) {
    // When the image is clicked...
    image.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        modal.innerHTML = '<div class="modal-content"><img src="' + event.target.src + '"><br><span>' + event.target.alt + '</span></div>';
        modal.style.display = 'block';
    });
});

// When the user clicks somewhere in the "modal" area it automatically closes itself
modal.addEventListener('click', function () {
    this.style.display = 'none';
});
```

I didn't bother to put any effect on the *modal* element, I was simply controlling the *hide* and *show* properties and didn't cared about `fadeIn` or `fadeOut` that were mentioned in your code.

The easiest and fastest way to make some animations, would be making use of some third-party animation library such as [Animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) that comes with tons of cool effects to work with.